# Create new Static List in Marketo via Marketo API

Tags: marketo

Is there a way to create a new static list in Marketo using the SOAP or REST API? I see I can Add Leads to an Existing List using REST API, but if I want to create a new static list and then add new leads to that static list all through API, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to do so. I'm guessing you're trying to "tag" people by putting them in certain lists when things happen? What you can try is have a data field be updated by a trigger campaign that's dynamic. then later search by it?

I'm making some assumptions.